# How to understand the Anorm parser?

Tags: playframework-2.0, anorm

From http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTodoList

What does the "~" do and why I don't need a point before map?

```
val task = {
  get[Long]("id") ~ 
  get[String]("label") map {
    case id~label => Task(id, label)
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` operator is inspired from the Scala [parser combinators](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers), it allows to extract two column values from a row.

There is no point before `map` because in Scala you are [not required to write points](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/118).